# KendoUI Web - datepicker display formatting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, datepicker

I'm using Kendo-UI Web.  The datepicker display is "blown out", fonts much larger than expected, and just looks way too large than it should be.

I am quite positive this is because of my poor css ability.  I believe something I've done in my css is conflicting with KendoUI and is causing an override of style.  I used chrome debug tools to try to hone in on what I may have done to cause the styling issue and just cannot find it!

**I have attached a screenshot of what is happening.**
[image: I have attached a screenshot of what is happening.]

I'd like the datepicker to display in the style as kendo would natively show it, it's it's style and all.

I hope this makes sense.

Here is the demo site you can use if it helps:  **http://dev.skoovy.com**

**Username:** test@test.com
**Password:** test123

1. Click on the "Add +" link at the top right of the page in the header
2. Select "Add A Place" option In the URL field, use
3. http://www.mytabletbooksqa.com/ProductImages/test1.gif When the next
4. screen loads with the tabs, click on "When"
5. select the datepicker icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS after after the Kendo.css is declared:

```
.k-popup .k-calendar {
  font-size: 13px !important;
 }
```

I think this matches the CSS Font-size you are looking for:

[image]